# Create a dictionary of dataframes with string keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dictionary of dataframes looping through the keys. It seems there is a problem with the keys being strings so that I am getting the following error:

```
stocks[key]=pd.DataFrame()
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), 
numpy.newaxis 
(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My code is:

```
for key in stocks: 
n+=1
stocks[key]=pd.DataFrame()
```

where keys are APPL, AMZN

As simple as that :S What could be happening?

Comment: what is `stocks`?

Comment: print(stocks) will give ['AMZN' 'AAPL' 'FB' 'GOOGL']

Comment: There you go. It is not a `dict`. So just instantiate a dict and change it.. e.g. `stocks_dict = {}` and `stocks_dict[key] = ...`

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem. Surprisingly you cant call a dictionary by a string=key as a dataframe column for instance. The key needs to be casted as an integer.

So what I did was the following
    for i,key in enumerate(stocks):
    stocks[i]=aux_matrix

Comment: You are wrong. You *can* access a dict with a string. The thing is: you have a numpy array, and thus you are changing the values in the indexes `enumerate` yielded

Comment: The statement "Surprisingly you cant call a dictionary by a string=key as a dataframe column for instance. The key needs to be casted as an integer" is false. The key of a dictionary can be a string for sure